# Linking to a specific section of a page from Google custom search engine result

Tags: search-engine, anchor

I would like to know if there is a way when using Google custom search engine to have Google CSE link to a page with a URL like this

> http://www.mysite.com/mysection/mysectionarticles.html#myarticle234

or something close to that.

Let’s say Google would find the searched words in a certain part of the page it could be in a  or after an anchor or something like that and would supply in the search result a way to link to this specific section of the page.

So if you have big pages the user wouldn't have to scroll through the page to find the relevant part he saw in the CSE snippet.

It could also be used if you have a dynamic page that change state using JavaScript. Part of the page is hidden to the user until he does an action in the pages, but this hidden content was indexed by Google because it’s part of the page. So when the user clicks on the link in the search result he ends up on a page and can’t find the relevant part because it’s hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google's support for [structured/rich data](http://googlecustomsearch.blogspot.com/2009/10/structured-custom-search.html)  and [ajax urls for crawling](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/index.html) (aka hash-bangs).  One or both of them ought give you access to the pages with the right things displayed.